# Grid view w/ progress bars?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

Trying to decide on the best element to use for a grid view, pretty much exactly like the one you'd see in uTorrent or any other upload/download client. Specifically, I want to have a 'progress' column too (with progress bars). Using VS2010/.NET4. Haven't really started the project yet, so either WPF or WinForms are fine. What would you recommend?

Comment: I would recommend WPF, but you tagged it as WinForms.

Comment: @Henk: Perhaps I'm mistaken. I really don't know what you call the controls. I go to `File > New Project > C# > Windows Forms Application`. And it gives me a bunch of controls that I can drag onto my form. Whatever you call those.

Comment: Mark, go `File > New Project > C# > WPF Application` for a whole new world.

Comment: Mark - Henk's point is that there are now two platforms for building desktop clients in visual studio - Windows Forms Applications and Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) applications. Unless you must use Windows Forms, then use WPF (create a new WPF project, not a Windows Forms one) WPF gives you much better options for UI.

Comment: @David: Ohhh.... you're right. This is a whole new world. Haven't seen this before. WinForms was always listed first, didn't realize I had alternatives :D Still....which WPF control will fit the bill then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, you can stuff ProgressBars right in there:

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" HeadersVisibility="Column" GridLinesVisibility="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Uri, Mode=OneWay}" Header="Uri" IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Size, Mode=OneWay}" Header="Size" IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Progress">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ProgressBar Value="{Binding Path=Progress, Mode=OneWay}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Eta, Mode=OneWay}" Header="Eta" IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Priority, Mode=OneWay}" Header="Priority" IsReadOnly="True" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Took a bit of fumbling with my near-0 knowledge of WPF, but it's looking pretty sweet so far.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to write some of it yourself this might be helpful:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/769ca9d6-1e9d-4d76-8c23-db535b2f19c2/